# How much will a timer event slow down my code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, timer

I am currently building a rather large web based application. My job is to build the interface using JavaScript and jQuery. Eventually the application will be using Ajax, C# and SQL. There is thus rather a lot going on at any point of time.

I need to listen for an event. Currently I am using a combination of mouseover and mouseout events to trigger this event, but it does not cover all my basses.

I am thus considering using a JavaScript interval timer to periodically check if the event should fire. I am hesitant to do so for fear of slowing down my code too much.

My question then is **how much will this slow down the rest of my code?**

I realize that it depends on how much code is run in the corresponding function, so here is a quick list of things that happen:

- I obtain the mouse coordinates using e.pageX and e.pageY.
- I check the element that you are currently hover on using document.elementFromPoint.
- I check if the element mentioned above has
  a parent of a specific class with a .closest
- If so, the event is fired.

So in conclusion, **I want to know if doing the above every few milliseconds will slow down my application noticeably**.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest actually measuring this.

Comment: Why not using jquery trigger to fire your event and then with 'bind' to catch it? Something like:  $.trigger('myCustomEvent', ['bla-bla'])

Comment: Agree, have to test it. It shouldn't be too tricky to vary your interval time and check a balance between UX and performance

Comment: Actually the minimal interval is 13-15, also depends on code running. 
jQuery using 13. Info in case you will choose to stick to interval.
If you function will not execute within this time, the second call will fall into stack, the rest will get canceled.

Comment: @ValentinRusk: Where did you get that numbers? Minimum timeout in HTML5 is 4ms.

Comment: @plunder: Why do mouseover/-out not cover all your needs? Show us the code and what you want to achieve, this should be possible using normal DOM events.

Comment: I have managed to avoid using the time out event. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Did any of our answers help you for your decision to avoid the timeout event? If so, you could upvote and accept an answer to help future users which have the same question. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @w4rumy: I managed to avoid having to add a listener that is constantly running, so in my case the question became a bit of a moot point. Instead I do something similar with a combination of mouseenters and mousemoves. This way I avoid having the code run all the time, and only run it when the mouse is interacting with specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment than an answer, but too much for the comments box.

Surely this should work:

```
$('.myClass').on('click', '*', function () {
    ...
});
```

or

```
$(documnt).on('click', '.myClass *', function () {
    ...
});
```

depending on whether `.myClass` elements are created at `DOMContentLoaded` or created by AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not exactly what I meant. I am not having trouble attaching events to newly generated objects. I need to register that an element is hovered on without moving the mouse. An element might animate to beneath the mouse. This element is not allowed to trigger any events whilst animating. Once the element stops moving, I then needs to register that I am hovering on it, without the mouse moving.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/8tfnk/1/) of how a Javascript interval timer will slow down an application:

HTML:

```
Function calls: <span id="info"></span>
<br>
<input type="text"/>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        foo();
    }, 13);
});
var calls = 0;

function foo() {
    calls++;
    $("#info").html(calls);
    fib(35); // calculate fibonacci numbers
}

function fib(n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}​
```

Try to enter some text in the textbox and you will see how unresponsive the application gets. Depending on your PC's hardware, you will see your entered text with more or less delay. Changing the parameter of the `fib()` function will make the application "faster" (lower number as parameter) or "slower" (higher number of parameter). [A low number](http://jsfiddle.net/8tfnk/) (meaning the function is executed fast) will not decrease the performance of your application.

Therefore, for your current case, I think the interval timer will not slow down your application noticably. But there are a few points to consider:

- Is the application only used on desktop browsers with fast hardware?
- Is the application also used by mobile devices/tablets? These often have a worse performance.
- For now, the interval timer does only really simple things. But what about the future? Maybe sometime more and more functionality is added to it because it is the easiest way for developers to do it.

Therefore, I would suggest to avoid the interval timer, if possible.